# How to show newsletter subscription date on grid?

Tags: php, magento

I want to show newsletter subscription date on **Newsletter Subscribers** Grid.

I am using magento 1.8.1.

How it will be possible.

Please suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, There isn't a subscription date stored when the customer subscribes, you will have to:

1. Add a `subscription_date` column to the newsletter_subscriber table
2. Override `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber` and in `subscribe` function, add code to set the subscription date to the model before saving `$this->setSubscriptionDate(yourDateGoesHere)`
3. Then, in order to show it int the backend, you will have to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid` and add this code in `_prepareColumns` function, just place it in the place you want it to show.

$this->addColumn('subscription_date', array(
'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Date'),
'index'     => 'subscription_date',
'type'      => 'datetime',
'align'     => 'center',
'gmtoffset' => true
    ));

Comment: in database change_status_at also a field.
Can we use this otherwise it is using for other purpose.

Comment: When the customer subscribes, this field remains null, its only changed when the user unsubscribes or "changes the status", so if you plan to use its as the "subscription date", you might lose the value stored there